# The last part of the box (bottom)

Tags: html, css

I need to set fotter of each book to the bottom.
I don't know how to do that. I am enclosing the entire HTML and CSS code.
I don’t know what I need to do to keep the footer at the bottom.
I set the width and height of each individual box. If height stayed on "car;" then he would solve but part of the problem. I do not know what to do. I need this code.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto);

.books{
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 290px;
  margin-right: 290px;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box-area {
  padding-top: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.single-box {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0.1px #888888;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 320px;
  height: 280px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d1f6f1 30%, white 30%);
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.footer-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
  
.img-area1 {
  background-image: url(Screenshot_2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 18%;
  background-position-y: 8%;
  background-position-x: 8%;
  }

.img-area2 {
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  }

.img-area3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.img-area3 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.img-area3 img.img-front:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-text {
  margin-left: 110px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.delete-book {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.delete-book-permanently {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding-left: 20%;
  color: grey;
}

p {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 6%;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.autor {
  color: #adadad;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 110px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.header-text2 {
  color: #545454;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.img-text {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.img-text p {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;

}

.zvjezdica {
  background-color: #b2eaf0;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #b2eaf0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  text-align: right;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #404040;
  min-width: 320px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}


.dropbtn:hover {color: white;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #404040; color: white;}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4a4a4a;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List Grid View Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="list-grid.css"/>
    <script src="list-grid.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="books">Books
      <div class="img-area3">
          <img src="list.png" alt="" class="img-back">
          <img src="grid.png" alt="" class="img-front">
      </div>
    </span>
      <div class="box-area">
        <div class="single-box">
            <div class="img-area1">
               <div class="img-text">
                  <span class="header-text"><strong>The Wizard of Oz</strong></span>
                    <p>Dorothy found herself riding easily between two of the biggest Monkeys, one of them the King himself. They had made a chair of their hands and were careful not to hurt her. "Why do you have to obey the charm of the Golden Cap?"</p>
                    <span class="autor">L. Frank Baum</span>
                <div class="zvjezdica">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                      <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                      <a href="#">Move book</a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <div style="display: inline;">
                          <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                          <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                <div class="img-area2">
                  <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                  <span class="header-text2">16</span>
              </div>
              </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="single-box">
            <div class="img-area1">
               <div class="img-text">
                  <span class="header-text"><strong>Mobi Dick</strong></span>
                    <p>Roound the world! There is much in that sound to inspire proud feelings; but where to does all that circum navigation conduct? Only through number less perils to the very point when we started, where those that we left behind secure, were all the time before us.</p>
                    <span class="autor">Herman Melville</span>
                <div class="zvjezdica">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                      <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                      <a href="#">Move book</a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <div style="display: inline;">
                          <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                          <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                <div class="img-area2">
                  <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                  <span class="header-text2">16</span>
              </div>
              </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="single-box">
            <div class="img-area1">
               <div class="img-text">
                  <span class="header-text"><strong>The War of the Worlds</strong></span>
                    <p>"What news from the common?" I said. "People seem fair silly about the common," sad the woman over the gate.</p>
                    <span class="autor">L. Frank Baum</span>
                <div class="zvjezdica">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                      <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                      <a href="#">Move book</a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <div style="display: inline;">
                          <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                          <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                <div class="img-area2">
                  <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                  <span class="header-text2">16</span>
              </div>
              </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="single-box">
            <div class="img-area1">
               <div class="img-text">
                  <span class="header-text"><strong>At the Earth's Core</strong></span>
                    <p>I wonderewd why these agile creatures required connecting bridges between the trees, but later when I saw the motley aggregation of half-savage beasts which they kept within their village I realized the necessity for the pathways.</p>
                    <span class="autor">Edgar Rice Burroughs</span>
                <div class="zvjezdica">
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                      <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                      <a href="#">Move book</a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <div style="display: inline;">
                          <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                          <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                <div class="img-area2">
                  <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                  <span class="header-text2">16</span>
              </div>
              </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-area">
          <div class="single-box">
              <div class="img-area1">
                 <div class="img-text">
                    <span class="header-text"><strong>A princess of Mars</strong></span>
                      <p>I drew rein on a little level promontory overlooking the trail below and to my left, and saw the party of pursuing savages disappearing around the point of a neighboring peak.</p>
                      <span class="autor">Edgar Rice Burroughs</span>
                  <div class="zvjezdica">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                        <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                        <a href="#">Move book</a>
                        <a href="#">
                          <div style="display: inline;">
                            <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                            <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                          </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                  <div class="img-area2">
                    <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                    <span class="header-text2">16</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>


              <div class="single-box">
                  <div class="img-area1">
                     <div class="img-text">
                        <span class="header-text"><strong>Alice in Wonderland</strong></span>
                          <p>The Hatter shook his head mournfully.'Not I!' he replied. 'We quarrelled last March - just before HE want mad, you know -'</p>
                          <span class="autor">Lewis Carrol</span>
                      <div class="zvjezdica">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                          <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                            <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                            <a href="#">Move book</a>
                            <a href="#">
                              <div style="display: inline;">
                                <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                                <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                              </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                      <div class="img-area2">
                        <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                        <span class="header-text2">16</span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </div>


                  <div class="single-box">
                      <div class="img-area1">
                         <div class="img-text">
                            <span class="header-text"><strong>The Scarlet Plague</strong></span>
                              <p>It was at this point that Harelip rose to gis feet, an expression of huge contempt on his face. "Granser," he announced, "you make me sick with your gabble.</p>
                              <span class="autor">Jack London</span>
                          <div class="zvjezdica">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                              <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                              <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                                <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                                <a href="#">Move book</a>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <div style="display: inline;">
                                    <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                                    <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                                  </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                          <div class="img-area2">
                            <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                            <span class="header-text2">16</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="single-box">
                          <div class="img-area1">
                             <div class="img-text">
                                <span class="header-text"><strong>Around the World in 80 days</strong></span>
                                  <p>Nothing could be more simple. Indeed, it was all so simple that Fix and Passepartout felt their hearts beating as if they would crack. They were listening for the whistle agreed upon, when suddenly savage cries resounded in the air, accompanied by reports which certainly did not issue from the car where the duelists were.</p>
                                  <span class="autor">Jules Verne</span>
                              <div class="zvjezdica">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                  <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                                    <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                                    <a href="#">Move book</a>
                                    <a href="#">
                                      <div style="display: inline;">
                                        <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                                        <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                              <div class="img-area2">
                                <img src="baseline_star_black_24dp.png" width="23px" height="23px" style="filter: invert(32%) sepia(0%) saturate(2306%) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(94%) contrast(89%);">
                                <span class="header-text2">16</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
        

        
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc6lc.png)

Comment: Please don't paste your entire web page, create a minimal reproducible example of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is your friend, think about what size you want everything else to be and the rest will fall into place. For instance, if you want the footer to be at the bottom, the description should expand to fill the empty space, pushing it to the bottom.

I had to rewrite large sections of your code due to old tags and typos.

```css
.book{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  width: 320px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: #d1f6f1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0.1px #888888;
}

.content{
  margin-left: 15%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
}

.title{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description{
  flex-grow: 2;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.author{
  color: #adadad;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.footer{
  background-color: #b2eaf0;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #b2eaf0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  text-align: right;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #404040;
  min-width: 320px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}


.dropbtn:hover {color: white;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #404040; color: white;}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4a4a4a;}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="title">The Wizard of Oz</div>
    <div class="description">Dorothy found herself riding easily between two of the biggest Monkeys, one of them the King himself. They had made a chair of their hands and were careful not to hurt her. "Why do you have to obey the charm of the Golden Cap?"
    </div>
    <div class="author">L. Frank Baum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">•••</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Edit book details</a>
                      <a href="#">Duplicate book</a>
                      <a href="#">Move book</a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <div style="display: inline;">
                          <span class="delete-book">Delete book</span>
                          <span class="delete-book-permanently">Delete this book permanently</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laif !!! :)

Comment: @donn_GOD if this answered your question, please mark it as such